# Is $\omega^{n/2}=-1$ in any ring if $\omega$ is a primitive nth-root of unity and $n$ is an even number?

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory, primitive-roots

I know this statement is true when we are working with the complex numbers, but I can't find out a way to prove it in any ring. I tried assuming by contradiction that $\omega^{n/2}=k\neq -1$ but can't get anywhere.

Thanks!

Edit: I added that $\omega$ is also a primitive (not only a nth root of unity) and that $n$ is even.

Comment: What does $\omega^{n/2}$ mean, if $n$ is odd?

Comment: n is even and i am multiplying the primitive nth root of unity (\omega) n/2 times.

Comment: If you want $n$ to be even, you must edit that information into the body of your question.

Comment: Ok! Thanks. I just edited it

Comment: Good. Now: $3^2=1$ in the ring of integers modulo eight, but $3\ne-1$ in that ring.

Comment: Any thoughts about my comment, or about ancient's answer?

Comment: Yes! Thank you, i see it now

Comment: @GerryMyerson wait, but 3 isn't a primitive 2-root of unity in the ring mod 8. 3 doesnt generate all the 2-roots of unity in mod 8

Comment: You should explain how you define a primitive nth root of unity in a ring that is not a field.

Answer (score 4):

Consider what happens in the ring of $2\times 2$ matrices over $\mathbb{C}$.

Take, for example $\omega=\text{diag}(i,1)$. Then $\omega^4=\text{diag}(1,1)=I$, but $\omega^2=\text{diag}(-1,1)\not= I$.

Comment: In this example your $\omega$ is not a primitive 4th root of unity, its just a 4th root of unity.

Comment: It is a primitive 4th root of unity in the sense that $\omega^k \neq 1$ for all $0 < k < 4$. (But it is not a primitive 4th root of unity in the sense that every other 4th root of unity is a power of $\omega$.)

Comment: @punctureddusk : that's a good point.

Answer (score 1):

I came to this: since $\omega$ is a primitive nth root of unity, then it generates all the nth roots of unity. Then, there must exist a $0\leq k\leq n-1$ such that $ \omega^k=-1$. By contradiction, lets supose that $k\neq n/2$. If $k<n/2$ then $\omega^{2k}=1$ so $\omega$ was not a primitive nth root of unity. Else if $k>n/2$ then $\omega^{2k}=\omega^{2k-n}\omega{n}=\omega^{2k-n}\cdot 1=1$, and because $2k-n<n$ then $\omega$ is not a primitive but only a root.

In both cases its a contradiction, so we conclude that $\omega^{n/2}=-1$.